# How to ensure e-mail deliverability with a single opt-in?

Tags: email, spam

I have a mailing list of opt-in only recipients. No e-mail confirmation was sent after registration. Now, I need to send a newsletter to the entire mailing list. I have tested on seeder e-mails in Gmail, Hotmail and Yahoo. The newsletter reached the inboxes in Yahoo (but with blocked images), while it ended in spam in Gmail and Hotmail. Only after I added the sending address to the seeders' address-book did the newsletter drop in the inbox.

My main concern is, how can I ensure that the newsletter will be delivered in the inboxes of the mailing list if none of the recepients have the sending address in their address book?

Comment: Are you after a technical solution to this?

Comment: If technical implementation is required in a solution, I can find a way around it

Comment: In short, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

> No e-mail confirmation was sent after registration.

This is bad, as it allows anyone to sign up any random email address to the newsletter.  It might also explain why your newsletter ends up in the Spam folder.

> how can I ensure that the newsletter will be delivered in the inboxes of the mailing list if none of the recepients have the sending address in their address book?

You can't. Otherwise, spammers would have an easy life. What you need to do is to ask the recipient to add the newsletter sender's address to their addressbook. But first, put into place email confirmation; if you don't do this your newsletters will be always at risk to be treated as spam.

Comment: Thank you, dr01, for your input. But, if this is impossible as you say, then how does a service like SurveyMonkey gets its e-mails to thousands of inboxes with no problem when you send out a survey? And, that even works with accounts that never received any e-mail from you before.

Comment: That's all a matter of reputation from users; well-known services will almost certainly reach the inbox while shady services will get negatively flagged and will end up being considered as spam. Surveymonkey has a zero-tolerance spam policy.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, dr01. I have checked their policy and my implementation aligns with it. However, I am not sure even SurveyMonkey can be confident if recipients are truly opt-in. They can only find out if the unsubscribe or complaint rates are high, but this takes place after their e-mails reach recipients' inboxes. The question remains, how do they achieve such a high reach rate?

Comment: Because they demonstrated to be a legitimate service. Trust is built over time. When they started their business their reach rate was probably not so high.

Comment: I actually checked SurveyMonkey's score on Mail tester and they got 6.4/10 whereas I lifted mine from 5/10 to 9/10. And, yet, theirs gets into inboxes and mine doesn't. Might it be the problem in the sending domain and the fact that Gmail and Hotmail could simply put it on constant spam?

Comment: Gmail, Hotmail and other mail providers perform checks on incoming email messages (SPF, RBL, etc) to decide whether it's legitimate or spam. You have to verify that your domain passes these tests. This is off-topic on UX so you should open a new question on ServerFault.